# How to Get rid of \r\n in a string

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to get messages from Gmail in C# 
but the message body comes like this `"\r\n\r\nBODY\r\n\r\n"` 
How can I get the `"BODY"` out of the string ?
I tried to loop through it but I found out that when looping the `"\r"` becomes a `" "`

Comment: You can replace \r\n from your text file using Replace method

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can [use `String.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) to remove all leading and trailing whitespace form a given string.  Something like this:

```
var body = inputString.Trim();
```

This would cover `/r/n` characters, as well as any other whitespace.

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
string after = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
body = body.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user writes some text in a file, the Editor automatically appends CR|LF after each line.
CR or Carriage Return is denoted as **`\r`** 
LF or Line Feed is denoted as **`\n`**

These are normally invisible to us, but while reading a text file using some code process it also captures these escape sequences.

To avoid these character you can easily replace them using builtin C# function **`Replace`** method

You can use following code to get rid from **\r** and **\n**

```
str = str.Replace("\r\n","");
```

This will first find out all combined `\r\n` characters and then replaces this string with `""` (Blank string).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    string result= rawString.Replace(@"\r\n", " ").Trim().Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").Replace("\n", " ");
```